# What does the "&" keyword do on access caption property?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was looking at an Access demo database and I found that the captions for buttons were written something like this : `&btn1` and`&btn2`

Upon inspection I realized that the "&" keyword creates an underline on the letter immediately following it. But from the docs it seems like the "&" keyword has other functions but I do not understand what it is. Would you please clarify what this sentence means that I pulled form the docs at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.label.caption):

> You can use the Caption property to assign an access key to a label or
>   command button. In the caption, include an ampersand (&) immediately
>   preceding the character you want to use as an access key.

What does assigning an access key to a label mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyboard to access the control (or the control bound with the label) by pressing `Alt` and the letter following the `&` in the controls or labels caption.